# Change List format in Python

Tags: python

I have an List like down below

```
[['-6.167665', '106.904251'], ['-6.167665', '106.904251']]
```

How to make it like this?

```
[[-6.167665, 106.904251], [-6.167665, 106.904251]]
```

Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Looks like you want to covert strings to floats?

Comment: yes it seems i have a float dataframe that converted to strings if i make them into list, and i need them in list of float

Comment: If you have a dataframe, why don't you convert it to float in it rather than the list?

Comment: From a DataFrame: `df.astype(float).to_numpy().tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `float`.

```
original_list = [['-6.167665', '106.904251'], ['-6.167665', '106.904251']]
print(original_list)

new_list = [[float(i) for i in inner] for inner in original_list]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

For big arrays numpy would do the trick :

```py
import numpy as np
l1 = [['-6.167665', '106.904251'], ['-6.167665', '106.904251']]
l2 = np.array(l1, dtype=np.float32)
```

output:

```
[[-6.167665, 106.904251], [-6.167665, 106.904251]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
old = [['-6.167665', '106.904251'], ['-6.167665', '106.904251']]
new = [list(map(lambda string: float(string), item)) for item in old]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already have suggested the method of doing it, which is convert to float. The most efficient way to do it is map:

```
values = [['-6.167665', '106.904251'], ['-6.167665', '106.904251']]

float_values = [list(map(float, vals)) for vals in values]

print(float_values)
```

Gives you:

```
[[-6.167665, 106.904251], [-6.167665, 106.904251]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert it to floats

```
old = [['-6.167665', '106.904251'], ['-6.167665', '106.904251']]

new = [list(map(float, i)) for i in old]

new
[[-6.167665, 106.904251], [-6.167665, 106.904251]]
```